# AWS SQS is not waiting for the queue being process in before save

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to hold the beforeSave() for coming back the response from AWS SQS Queue, My code is as follows:

```
      var promise =  Parse.Promise.as();

        return promise.then(function(){

            return sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err, data) {

                if (err){ 
                    console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                    return Parse.Promise.error(err);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Message Sent:");

                    return getSQSMessage(randomNumber).then(function(randomString){

                        var query = new Parse.Query("Class");
                        return query.get('someID').then(function (company) {
                            return Parse.Promise.as();
                        }, function (err) {
                            return Parse.Promise.error(err);
                        });
                    },function(err){
                        return Parse.Promise.error(err);
                    });
                }

            });

        },function(err){
            return Parse.Promise.error(err);
        });
```

So this code is not waiting till getting the response from AWS SQS Queue.

Apologies if I'm not able to explain.

Thanks

Comment: You're trying to return things inside a callback function. That's not going to work. I would suggest using promises only, instead of a mix of promises and callbacks.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkB ! Let me try this one.